# Getting $q.reject() error message in $error object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form where I'm using ng-show to display or hide an element when the postcode doesn't exist.

**View**

```
<input type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" ng-model="project.postcode" required integer postcode>    
<span ng-show="form.postcode.$error.postcode">That post code does not exist!</span>
```

**The postcode validation directive**

```
  .directive('postcode', function($q, $timeout, ParseService) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

                ctrl.$asyncValidators.postcode = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

                    var def = $q.defer();
                    ParseService.getRawObject(new Parse.Query("Zone")
                        .equalTo('postCode', parseInt(modelValue)).ascending('order')).then(function(results){

                        if(results.length == 1)
                                def.resolve();
                        else if(results.length > 1) {
                            def.reject('multiple');
                            scope.postcodeerror = 'multiple';
                            scope.postcodetowns = results;
                        }
                        else
                            def.reject();
                    });

                    return def.promise;
                };
            }
        };
```

All works well for the regular resolve and reject, but when I'm rejecting with the 'multiple' error code, I would like to evaluate this within the $error object on form.postcode...

i.e

```
<span ng-show="form.postcode.$error.postcode=='multiple'">This post code has multiple suburbs assigned to it!</span>
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Or do I just need to set something in scope?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code of the `postcode` directive (no pun intended)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked [Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L596) and it simply doesn't use the data returned by the rejected promise. But you can do that yourself by calling `$setValidity`:

```
.then(function(results) {
    scope.postcodetowns = results;
    ctrl.$setValidity('postcode', results.length === 0);
    ctrl.$setValidity('postcode_multiple', results.length > 1);
    def.resolve();
}
return def.promise;
```

And now you can use `form.postcode.$error.postcode_multiple` with `ngShow`:

```
<span ng-show="form.postcode.$error.postcode_multiple">
    This post code has multiple suburbs assigned to it!
</span>
```

Or even better, with `ngMessages`:

```
<div ng-messages="form.postcode.$error">
    <span ng-message="postcode">That post code does not exist!</span>
    <span ng-message="postcode_multiple">This post code has multiple suburbs assigned to it!</span>
</div>
```